# Propagating debug info and using exceptions

Tags: c++, exception, debugging, try-catch

I sometime encounter the next problem - how to use exceptions, while maintaining debug context from various stack calls. I'll present it with a simple example

```
void foo()
{
   for (int i=0;i<100;++i)
   {
      int j = rand();
      factor(j);
   }
}

void factor(int j)
{
   if (is_prime(j))
     throw "oh no, j is prime!";

   // ...
}
```

Now, my exception has the 'local' issue, and can show me what `j` is, if I want. However, many times I want to know the context of the issue, in this case  I want to have `i`. I can then give a more meaningful error to the user, e.g. in the i-th round I got a prime j.
There are a few obvious solutions but they all seem not that good.

1. pass the debug context down the function calls. so here I'll send `i` to `factor`. This only adds parameter to the functions and of course, I could have more than two functions in the chain of calls. Maybe it's only the 10th function that is being called that generates the error. It also forces specific type of debug parameters on the lower functions which binds them to the specific use case.
2. I could do a try-catch in `foo`, catch the exception thrown by `factor`, than add the debug context `i` and rethrow. But that means I'm using exceptions, but I'm catching and rethrowing which looks more like C style return codes. It also fills the code with try-catch statements.
3. I could use C style return codes, but then I loose the clarity that exceptions bring (like the previous solution).
4. I could put debug data on global variables. I would do that in small applications, but for large, complex, multithreaded ones, there would be a management over head for that global information.

Are there better approaches to that?

Comment: I'm using `std::expected` from C++23 extensively in my code for error handling. I expect that there will be more support to use it more naturally in C++26.

Comment: In this particular case, when not being prime is a precondition for `factor`, `foo` could check that before calling `factor`, Generally, if the condition happens often and only one level down, exceptions are not a good fit.